# Why not sell the stuff instead of throwing away?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In the Television series, How I met your mother, Season 8, Episode 23 - Something Old, why are Lily and Marshall throughing all the stuff they are unable to take in the bermudda triangle and not selling it? Like a yard sale or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They appeared to be short on time, and were trying to get rid of things they had grown attached too. So throwing it out was likely easier than trying to sell, but I had the same thought. Why not sell it?